# Gradle - subprojects exclude parent defined project dependency

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-management

How can I exclude parent defined `compile project` dependency?

Structure of modules is as follows:

```
- build.gradle
- settings.gradle
- MAIN_MODULE_1
  - build.gradle
- MODULE1
  - build.gradle
- MODULE2
  - build.gradle
- MODULE3
  - build.gradle
- MODULE4
  - build.gradle
```

And dependency model should be:

```
- MODULE1 <- MAIN_MODULE_1
- MODULE2 <- MAIN_MODULE_1
- MODULE3 <- MAIN_MODULE_1
- MODULE4 <- MAIN_MODULE_1
```

Which means, having

```
// build.gradle
subprojects {
  apply plugin: 'java'
  dependencies {
    compile project('MAIN_MODULE_1')
  }
}

// settings.gradle
include ':MAIN_MODULE_1'
include ':MODULE1'
include ':MODULE2'
include ':MODULE3'
include ':MODULE4'
```

will create circular dependency of `MAIN_MODULE_1` on itself, which is wrong.

and having the dependency in each module (of total count not 4 but 120) seems wrong to me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can conditionally apply the dependency only if you are not in project `MAIN_MODULE_1`:

```
  dependencies {
    if (!project.name.equals("MAIN_MODULE_1")) {
      compile project(':MAIN_MODULE_1')
    }
  }
```

The answer below is a cleaner solution.

Comment: Wow, it was really pain in the arse, but it helped. Thank you

Answer (score 14):

You can use the configuration block :

```
project(':MAIN_MODULE_1') {
  apply plugin: 'java'
}

configure(subprojects - project(':MAIN_MODULE_1')) {
  apply plugin: 'java'
  dependencies {
    compile project('MAIN_MODULE_1')
  }
}
```

The answer is coming from this other question [Gradle exclude plugin in main project for specific subproject(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906806/gradle-exclude-plugin-in-main-project-for-specific-subprojects)

Comment: Clarify what this code does please? That "-" is throwing me. Java background.

Comment: I think it is an arithmetic operation and translates to "the set of subprojects minus the subproject `MAIN_MODULE_1`".