# Gradle exclude plugin in main project for specific subproject(s)

Tags: java, android, gradle, build.gradle

I am working on a larger project that contains many subprojects which are all build with gradle.
Generally all projects are java projects, therefore in the main build.gradle script

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
}
```

is specified for all projects.

However I need to either remove the plugin for a certain subtree of projects or explicitly exclude the the projects from the plugin.

Heres a rough overview of the project layout

```
+ Main
+-- javaApplications
+-- javaLibs
+-- Android
+-----AndroidApps
+-----AndroidLibs
```

Android/* does not need the java plugin.
What is the best solution to achieve this? Note: I cannot change the project structure.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This should do the trick (when placed in root `build.gradle` script)

```
configure(allprojects - project(':Android')) { //or ':Android:AndroidApps' not sure
    println "applying java plugin to $project"
    apply plugin: 'java'  
}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter! :) Sometimes it needs `configure`, sometimes not. What is the general rule?

Comment: I played around with your code a bit -  Apparently it only removes only the specified project from allprojects. Can this be modified to work for parent projects e.g. :Android as well?

Comment: Yes, because it only removes one project from the whole set. Remove a collection of projects and it's done. Sth like `allprojects - project(':Android') - project(':Android').subprojects` should work.

Comment: @Opal The `configure` method is the generic way to configure an (arbitrary) collection of objects. For common cases (e.g. `allprojects` or `subprojects`), a special method is provided, which you'll find in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html).

Comment: The other option is to apply the plugin selectively in subproject build scripts.

Answer (score 18):

You can also do this way:

```
allprojects {
    if (!it.name.startsWith('Android')) {
        apply plugin: 'java'
    }
}
```